# Why is the "About me" field in a profile not Markdown enabled?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, profile-page

If you have such a good way to do formatting in questions/answers why isn't it used for the "about me" section on the profile page?

It looks easy to make and adds just a little bit more consistency.

Comment: It's quite annoying, isn't it? Through practically all of a SO site we have to think in Markdown to get our questions and answers looking right, but as soon as we go to change our bios, all that goes out the window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "about me" field is now Markdown-enabled!

(I agree we should have done this a year ago, but.. hey.. better late than never, right? *right?*)

Answer (score 3):

It has limited HTML capabilities such as bolding, italics, line breaks, h1 through h3's, and lists. I know there are more allowed tags but I can't remember where to find them. Links and images are also allowed.

You can view my profile as an example of the limited html capabilities (I have bolding, line breaks, lists, images, and links all throughout).

Comment: I believe it's exactly the same set of HTML that is allowed in questions/answers and is part of markdown set. But it shouldn't replace markdown :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user

Comment: Yes... but why no markdown?

Comment: What really annoys me is the new lines, just automate them dammit, why do I have to type `<br>`??

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same HTML that is allowed in questions without the Markdown parsing. Since there is not a Markdown editor attached to it.

Comment: I know that but it's not markdown :)