# Enable Markdown in the About Me field

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, markdown

The About Me field in the user profile doesn't have Markdown enabled, so for instance, if you leave empty lines, they don't count, and instead you have to use `<br>`.

At least make it so that newlines are not ignored, it's really annoying, having to put with html tags, in a simple "about me" field.

Related question: [Why is "About me" field in profile not markdown enabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2647/why-is-about-me-field-in-profile-is-not-markdown-enabled)

Comment: I guess it is supposed to be simple (like you said), hence just plain textbox.

Comment: @John, you see, comments will be forgotten into the mist of time. You don't get notifications for them, the question continues to sink into older pages that nobody looks at, etc. I bet you won't see this comment until you come back to this (for some weird reason) 10 monthes later.

Comment: @hasen j: I regularly check questions I have revised/commented, as long as they are visible in the activity tab of my user profile.

Comment: @John, alright cool. What I don't like about the other question's wording is it kinda sounds like someone is just whining, plus the opening sentence "This is a stupid question and I know the answer but". Plus it doesn't have a picture .. with hand-drawn circles

Comment: Your last point is a valid one, hasen j. But nevertheless the request is understandable and will be declined one way or another.