# Bullet list formatting Protip

Tags: support, list

I'm trying to format a bullet list with a title like this:

**this is the title**

- Waffles
- Ponies

How do I get rid of the space between the title and the bullet list?
I've searched in the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) but I have not found any helpful example.

It surely can be done because I've just seen [George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker) profile and he has something like this:

[image]

Mind to share this magic Protip?

Comment: (Given you want to get rid of the whitespace, I guess you've also used a line break –rather than a paragraph break– on purpose underneath that list. But just in case you did not: see [balpha's explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-you-should-press-return-key-2-times-to-insert-a-new-line/45635#45635) about the differences.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspecting the source of the about me section there, you'll see something interesting:

```
I'm a Software Developer. I'm also a PC. But I could be a Mac. 
I talk about software, programming, and usability on my 
<a href="http://blog.yapb.net" rel="nofollow"><strong>blog</strong></a>.
<hr>
<strong>What I'm Good at</strong>:
<ul>
    <li>Communicating</li>
    <li>Creating software that <strong>makes sense</strong></li>
    <li>Self-aggrandizing sentences (like these).</li>
</ul>
<br>
<strong>How to Reach me</strong>
<br>
Catch me on <a href="http://twitter.com/gortok" rel="nofollow"><strong>twitter</strong></a> or
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/georgestocker" rel="nofollow"><strong>Linked In</strong></a>.
If you want to see what I've done, check my <strong><a href="http://careers.stackoverflow.com/george-stocker" rel="nofollow">CV</a></strong>
or <strong><a href="http://blog.yapb.net/page/My-Portfolio.aspx" rel="nofollow">Portfolio</a></strong>.
```

There's a glaring lack of `<p>` tags. If you inspect any other post on the site, you'll notice that all texts are enclosed in `<p>` tags, because that's how Markdown rolls. So how did these profile 'about me' section go without Markdown? Looking through the Meta archive, I found this question: [Why is the "About me" field in a profile not Markdown enabled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2647/why-is-about-me-field-in-profile-is-not-markdown-enabled)

So basically, the only reason why that list looks like that is because the his profile's about me section was written without Markdown, in pure HTML, and was never edited after they enabled Markdown on those sections, so it retained the original HTML.