# Can I use CSS in the "About me" section of my Stack profile?

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page

When asking questions on any stack site, basic HTML is allowed.  I understand why you can only use the basics in questions; You are asking for information, and style is not all that important.  However, when writing a bio in the "About me" section of one's profile, style is more important because, in short, the *style* of the "About me" section can be considered to be *about you*.

If CSS styles were added, I would not mind if it too had limitations.  All I'm trying to do is use vertical alignment to make text next to an image appear vertically aligned with the image itself.

Is there a way of doing that without CSS?  Or is my hope lost?

Comment: for reference: this is the only html allowed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/158100 and that doesn't include any css options.

Comment: Well, in the beginning [it didn't even support markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2647/why-is-the-about-me-field-in-a-profile-not-markdown-enabled).